# CSS effect disappeared because of page reload

Tags: javascript, html, css, reload

There is a q&a bulletin board where user's questions is stored.
This board can show questions in order of priority, but I have a problem in this process.

I want to apply and persist CSS when a specific `<li>` tag is clicked.

The code is below. The `sortDatas()` function shows the q&a with the most *commentlikes* first.
For example, if you click *commentlike*, a parameter called *commentlike* is passed to `sortDatas()`, and data with the highest *commentlike* is fetched from the server so that it can be displayed at the top of the window.

What I want is that even after the execution of the `sortDatas()` function is finished, the css effect applied by the `changeBGColor()` function continues even after refreshing.

In the current situation, the alert appears the moment it is clicked, and then disappears as soon as the css is applied. (since the window refreshes immediately)

The reason seems clear. It seems that the `changeBGColor()` function should not be applied directly to the `onclick()` function. I understand why, but I don't know how to improve it. What should I do? Should I use the same concept as the `onload()` function?

c.f) Requests to the server to fetch data are handled asynchronously. (using `async`/`await`)

```html
<div class="filter-section">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active" id = "recent" onclick="sortDatas('recent'); changeBGColor('recent')" >recent</li><br>
                    <li class="active" id = "old" onclick="sortDatas('old'); changeBGColor('old')" >old</li><br>
                    <li class="active" id = "commentlike" onclick="sortDatas('commentlike'); changeBGColor('commentlike')">commentlike</li><br>
                    <li class="active" id = "answers" onclick="sortDatas('answers'); changeBGColor('answers')">answers</li><br>
                </ul>
</div>
```

```
<script>

    function sortDatas(obj){

        let url = new URL(window.location.href);
        url.searchParams.set('sort',obj);
        location.href=url;

    }

   function changeBGColor(category)
   {

       let c = document.getElementById(category);
        
       if(c.classList.contains("active"))
       {
           alert('1');
           c.classList.remove("active");
           c.classList.add("active-select");
       }
       else if(c.classList.contains("active-select"))
       {
           alert('2');
           c.classList.remove("active-select");
           c.classList.add("active");
       }
        
   }

</script>
```

Comment: Why not add the classes to the markup again, through the same JS function? If you change the markup through JS, a reload of the page will reset these changes

Comment: @NicoHaase   Do you mean to add the existing code inside the changeBGColor function inside the sortDatas function? I didn't quite understand.